# size mismatch, m1: [288 x 9], m2: [2592 x 256] at /tmp/pip-req-build-4baxydiv/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:197

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Here is the error I got

```
*** RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [288 x 9], m2: [2592 x 256] at /tmp/pip-req-build-4baxydiv/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:197
```

Here my model :

```
class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_actions, lr):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=4, out_channels=16, kernel_size=8, stride=4)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=4, stride=2)

        # You have to respect the formula ((W-K+2P/S)+1)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=32*9*9, out_features=256)
        self.out = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=num_actions)


    def forward(self, state):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        # (1) Hidden Conv. Layer
        self.layer1 = F.relu(self.conv1(state))

        # (2) Hidden Conv. Layer
        self.layer2 = F.relu(self.conv2(self.layer1))

        # (3) Hidden Linear Layer
        self.layer3 = self.fc(self.layer2)

        # (4) Output
        actions = self.out(self.layer3)

        return actions
```

The error is triggered at line `self.layer3 = self.fc(self.layer2)`. `state` is a pytorch tensor of shape `(1, 4, 84, 84)`.

The full traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/infinity/Projects/Exercice_Project/AI_Exercices/Atari_2600_Breakout.py", line 228, in <module>
    action = agent.choose_action(state, policy_network)
  File "/home/infinity/Projects/Exercice_Project/AI_Exercices/Atari_2600_Breakout.py", line 166, in choose_action
    return policy_net(state).argmax(dim=1).to(self.device)
  File "/home/infinity/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/infinity/Projects/Exercice_Project/AI_Exercices/Atari_2600_Breakout.py", line 101, in forward
    self.layer3 = self.fc(self.layer2)
  File "/home/infinity/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/infinity/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 87, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/home/infinity/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1372, in linear
    output = input.matmul(weight.t())
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [288 x 9], m2: [2592 x 256] at /tmp/pip-req-build-4baxydiv/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:197
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before `self.layer3 = self.fc(self.layer2)`, I had to add the line `input_layer3 = self.layer2.reshape(-1, 32*9*9)`.